# Stacking ML Algorithms in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, ensemble-learning

Is there a spark api to build stacking ensembles in spark or should one build them from scratch? I haven’t found any resources online about this topic

Comment: there are two implementations for tree-based ML models: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/mllib-ensembles.html Beside those, I guess you have to implement it by yourself

Comment: I think I could achieve this with pipelines, right? Although the data transformations would be quite painful because I will need to duplicate the datasets and add new empty columns to host the outputs of the lower level learners.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in the comment of AKSW, in the current Apache Spark MLlib there is only two specific implementations of Ensemble Models which are [Random Forests](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/ml-classification-regression.html#random-forests) for Bagging and [Gradient Boosted Trees](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/ml-classification-regression.html#gradient-boosted-trees-gbts) for Boosting.

For the stacking part I don't think there is something you can find on MLlib, you have to do it by your own by either :

1. Create a function to generate a Pipeline that would do stacking by adding your base learners with vector assemblers and the final stacking algorithm
2. Create a Meta Estimator that would take your base learners and your stacking algorithm as parameters

The second one is convenient because it can work with all the MLlib tools as [Tuning Tools](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/ml-tuning.html)

For the second solution I have made a library that contains a Boosting, Bagging and Stacking Meta-Estimators : [spark-ensemble](https://github.com/pierrenodet/spark-ensemble)

You can take some implementations ideas out of that !